# Javascript Loop Next 10 Days

Tags: javascript, loops, date, for-loop

I have the following code which I want to return an incremental date for the next 10 days

```js
const startingDay = new Date('2021-10-29');
const thisDay = new Date(startingDay);

for(var i=1; i<10; i++) {
    thisDay.setDate(startingDay.getDate() + i);
  console.log(thisDay);
}
```

which is great, but for some reason as soon as it hits Oct 31, it starts going up in months rather than days.

Why would that be?

Thanks

Comment: Just use do 10 loops of `thisDay.setDate(thisDay.getDate() + 1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altering your logic slightly will give you the desired behaviour, setDate() will not work the way you expect with multiple calls to the same date instance.

The reason is that, starting with November 01, at iteration #4, we'll be setting the date to 33 (29 + 4). The logic used by setDate will be to advance the date to the next month, December, since November has only 30 days, then advancing another 2 days to December 3. The same effect will happen for subsequent iterations.

By re-creating the `thisDay` variable on each iteration, the logic used by setDate will work as expected.

```js
const startingDay = new Date('2021-10-29');

for(var i= 1; i < 10; i++) {
    let thisDay = new Date(startingDay);
    thisDay.setDate(startingDay.getDate() + i);
    console.log(thisDay);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you Terry

Answer (score 2):

```
for(var i=1; i<10; i++) {
    thisDay.setDate(startingDay.getDate() + i);
```

Since you're looping from `1` to `i < 10`, you'll add more days as the loop progresses.

---

> I want to return an incremental date for the next 10 days

So why update `thisDay` with the `startingDay.getDate() + i` if you can just use `thisDay.getDate() + 1`:

```js
const startingDay = new Date('2021-10-29');
const thisDay = new Date(startingDay);

for(var i=1; i<10; i++) {
    thisDay.setDate(thisDay.getDate() + 1);
    console.log(thisDay);
}
```

```
"2021-10-30T00:00:00.000Z"
"2021-10-31T00:00:00.000Z"
"2021-11-01T01:00:00.000Z"
"2021-11-02T01:00:00.000Z"
"2021-11-03T01:00:00.000Z"
"2021-11-04T01:00:00.000Z"
"2021-11-05T01:00:00.000Z"
"2021-11-06T01:00:00.000Z"
"2021-11-07T01:00:00.000Z"
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the docs for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate .

It will automatically switch to the next or previous month if you provide a value that is out of range for the current month. This makes it easier to jump between months when adding days.

But the way you've coded your example, *you always start from the day of the original date, but edit the second date*:

i:1 | date = 2021-10-29 -> set day to 30th -> date = 2021-10-30

i:2 | date = 2021-10-30 -> set day to 31st -> date = 2021-10-31

i:3 | date = 2021-10-31 -> set day to 32nd -> date = 2021-11-01, since oct only has 31 days

i:4 | date = 2021-11-01 -> set day to 33rd -> date = 2021-12-03, since nov has 30 days, so adding 33 days to the first of nov, gives us 3rd of december

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the incorrect day due to month switching you can solve it using `Date()` itself.

```js
const startingDay = new Date('2021-10-29');
let thisDay = new Date(startingDay);

for(let i = 1; i<10; i++) {
      thisDay = new Date(Date.now() + i * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
      console.log(thisDay.getDate());
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ran for your help

Comment: Adding days as milliseconds doesn't work well in places where daylight saving is observed as not all days are 24 hours long.